# How to send other form data while uploading images using ajax, php and the image is not selected

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form which uploads images with progress bar. But selecting image is optional. It works fine when images are selected. **upload.php** gets both name and images. The problem is it can't send name or other form data while image is not selected.

the form-

```
<form id="uploadImage" action="upload.php" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>File Upload</label>
                            <input type="file" name="uploadFile[]" id="uploadFile" accept=".jpg, .png" multiple/>
                        </div>
                        <div id="preview"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" id="uploadSubmit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-info" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="targetLayer" style="display:none;"></div>
                    </form>
                    <div id="loader-icon" style="display:none;"><img src="loader.gif" /></div>
```

Javascript code-

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#uploadImage').submit(function(event){

            var x= document.getElementById("name").value;

            if (x == '')
                document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML= "name is required.";

            else
            {
                if($('#uploadFile').val())
                {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('#loader-icon').show();
                    $('#targetLayer').hide();
                    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                        target: '#targetLayer',
                        beforeSubmit:function(){
                            $('.progress-bar').width('50%');
                        },
                        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentageComplete)
                        {
                            $('.progress-bar').animate({
                                width: percentageComplete + '%'
                            }, {
                                duration: 1000
                            });
                        },
                        success:function(){
                            $('#loader-icon').hide();
                            $('#targetLayer').show();
                        },
                        resetForm: true
                    });
                }

                else
                {

                }
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

so while the image is not selected what to do in **else** part?

Comment: In your else block, use the same statements of the if block but (a) Remove the beforeSubmit block; and (b) Remove the uploadProgress block

Comment: great. have a nice day